# How do I access AppointmentItem being edited from a custom appointment FormRegion?

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office, office-interop, outlook-addin

I'm developing a custom Appointment FormRegion add-in for outlook.

1. I need to access to the AppointmentInfo object when the appointment
   has been created, in order to get data from that (date, subject,
   etc) and from the custom FormRegion to log it in a separate remote
   database.
2. If an appointment is being edited, I need to access the
   AppointmentInfo at the time the FormRegion is brought up in order to
   pull information from the said database and populate the fields in
   the cusom FormRegion.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, figured it out.

```
    using OutlookTools = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook;
    using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

    //....class definition, etc

    private void CustomFormRegion_FormRegionShowing(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {

        OutlookTools.FormRegionControl control = (OutlookTools.FormRegionControl)sender;
        Outlook.AppointmentItem item = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)control.OutlookItem;
    }
```

**EDIT:** Better yet...

```cs
//...
Outlook.AppointmentItem item = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)this.OutlookItem;
//...
```